# how to add large number of rows in excel with best performance

Tags: javascript, excel

i want to add large number of rows in my project using javascript in excel.
but every row having different index.
Now i am adding rows one by one but it takes too much time.
so what can i do to increase the performance.
i see on https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/12 they are using async approach to increase but i dont know how to use that async approach

[image]

Comment: Need a lot more information than that.  For starters, how large?  Please check out [mcve] as well as [ask] and the [tour].

Comment: Let's see the code you have so far that is "adding rows one by one".  Also your attached picture is too small.  Have you tried googling the asyc method yo saw on the bug report?  Show what you have so far.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507898/how-to-maximise-performance-for-table-row-addition-of-50k-rows-using-excel-java/47515817#47515817